# Microsoft Access database performance

Tags: performance, ms-access, query-performance

I wonder how MS Access manage to show long list of records when we want to browse theme in Datasheet view.

1 - Does it load limited amount of records on start-up and then load the remainder upon user interaction (scrolling for example)?

2 - Does it care about such things automatically or natively?

Thanks.